# Is there a way to make a player for iOS which plays IN an HTML document, and NOT fullscreen?

Tags: html, ios, video, mobile

I want to make a player in a website for iOS devices, but I don't want that it plays the video in fullscreen. I want the player that plays it inside the website, making it able to view both the website AND the video.

Witch would look something like this:

[image: This kind of player][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the html5 `<video>` element.

Comment: does that work for all ios devices? Because my iPhone still does full screen.

Comment: My understanding is that the iPhone will always play full screen but the iPad will let you play as you'd like

Comment: yea I found it out, thanks for your answer It's a pity though that iPhone can only play fullscreen